# Manually creating a PDA in the instruction function

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

I am trying to dynamically allocate a PDA with `system_program`'s `create_account` instruction, but I feel like I am missing some key piece of information. I keep getting an error saying:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
```

I managed to deduce that the `create_account` call itself is what fails; I am not sure if I passed in the wrong seeds, or if my signers on the frontend/context are configured wrong (previously I was going with a `Signer<'info>` directly, but then following the Anchor Book article on PDAs, I turned that into an unchecked account, for better or worse.

```
pub fn init_collection(
    _ctx: Context<InitCollection>,
) -> Result<()> {
    msg!("checking if account is initialized");
    if !_ctx.accounts.col.data_is_empty() {
        msg!("account is already initialized");
        return Ok(());
    }

    let acc = _ctx.accounts.borrow_mut();

    init_pda(
        &_ctx.accounts.col.to_account_info(), 
        &_ctx.accounts.rent, 
        14, 
        &crate::id(), 
        &_ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(), 
        &_ctx.accounts.system_program, 
        &[
            b"col".as_ref(),
            &[255],
        ])?;

    Ok(())
}



#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct  InitCollection<'info> {
    /// CHECK: Is checked in the program.
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"col".as_ref()], bump)]
    col: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: Is checked in the CPI.
    payer: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

For creating the account itself, I basically lifted the functionality from the anchor project:

```
pub fn init_pda<'a>(
    new_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    rent_key: &Sysvar<'a, Rent>,
    space: usize,
    owner: &Pubkey,
    payer: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    system_program: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    seeds_with_nonce: &[&[u8]],
) -> Result<()>
{
    let rent = &Rent::from_account_info(&rent_key.to_account_info())?;

    // If the account being initialized already has lamports, then
    // return them all back to the payer so that the account has
    // zero lamports when the system program's create instruction
    // is eventually called.
    let __current_lamports = new_account.lamports();
    if __current_lamports == 0 {
        // Create the token account with right amount of lamports and space, and the correct owner.
        let lamports = rent.minimum_balance(space);
        let cpi_accounts = anchor_lang::system_program::CreateAccount {
            from: payer.to_account_info(),
            to: new_account.to_account_info()
        };
        let cpi_context = anchor_lang::context::CpiContext::new(system_program.to_owned(), cpi_accounts);
        anchor_lang::system_program::create_account(cpi_context.with_signer(&[seeds_with_nonce]), lamports, space as u64, owner)?; // <== This seems to be where it's failing
    } else {
        // Fund the account for rent exemption.
        let required_lamports = rent
            .minimum_balance(space)
            .max(1)
            .saturating_sub(__current_lamports);
        if required_lamports > 0 {
            let cpi_accounts = anchor_lang::system_program::Transfer {
                from: payer.to_owned(),
                to: new_account.to_owned(),
            };
            let cpi_context = anchor_lang::context::CpiContext::new(system_program.to_owned(), cpi_accounts);
            anchor_lang::system_program::transfer(cpi_context, required_lamports)?;
        }
        // Allocate space.
        let cpi_accounts = anchor_lang::system_program::Allocate {
            account_to_allocate: new_account.to_owned(),
        };
        let cpi_context = anchor_lang::context::CpiContext::new(system_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts);
        anchor_lang::system_program::allocate(cpi_context.with_signer(&[seeds_with_nonce]), space as u64)?;
        // Assign to the spl token program.
        let cpi_accounts = anchor_lang::system_program::Assign {
            account_to_assign: new_account.to_owned()
        };
        let cpi_context = anchor_lang::context::CpiContext::new(system_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts);
        anchor_lang::system_program::assign(cpi_context.with_signer(&[seeds_with_nonce]), owner)?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? I can't seem to be able to figure out where exactly what I am missing.

Thank you!

Comment: In `init_collection` you add `&[255]` to the seeds, while you don't add that same byte in the Accounts struct. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @WalrusGumboot I was under an impression that's how you pass in the bump for the account. I tried passing it like that, after trying `_ctx.bumps.get("col").unwrap()", but both led to the same error. Passing in nothing for the bump also doesn't affect the error, so I'm a bit confused as to what to do.

Comment: @Reynevan can you share the init_pda method. Would clear the things that how you have utilized the method arguments. This is typical example of wrong seeds.